# Toolbar does not show 'Up arrow'

Tags: android, navigation, fragment, toolbar, android-toolbar

I have MainActivity which holds MapFragment. And I have few other framgents too amongst them is TabFragment which has user settings.

I added toolbar in my activity_main.xml which looks as below:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"

                app:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ToolbarStyle">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Depending on the fragment that is getting visibility, I change the ‘title’ and change navigation menu (hamburger menu) to Up arrow or vice versa. Below are the methods I used to do the same:

```
        //Method to show the toolbar..  
        protected void showToolbar(final boolean isAnimation) {
            if (mToolbar != null) {
                if (mActivity.getSupportActionBar() == null) {
                    mActivity.setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
                }

                if (isAnimation) {
                    mToolbar.animate().translationY(0)
                            .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator()).start();
                }
                if (mToolbar.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
                    mToolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                mActivity.getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
                mActivity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }


        //Method to change the title and color of the toolbar..  
        public void setToolbarColor(final String title, final int backgroundColor, final int textColor,
                                    final boolean isNavigationIcon) {
            if (mToolbar != null) {
                mToolbar.setTitle(title);
                mToolbar.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
                mToolbar.setTitleTextColor(textColor);

                if (mActivity.getSupportActionBar() == null) {
                    mActivity.setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
                }
                ActionBar actionBar = mActivity.getSupportActionBar();
                actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(isNavigationIcon); // disable the button
                actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(isNavigationIcon); // remove the left caret
                actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(isNavigationIcon); // remove the icon
            }
        }
```

Below is way I called these methods from onResume() of MapFragment:

```
public void onResume() {
        setToolbarColor(getString(R.string.title_main),
                ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.blue),
                ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.white),
                false);

        mActivity.unlockDrawer();
        showToolbar(true);
}
```

And this is the way I called those methods from onResume() of TabsFragment:

```
public void onResume() {
    setToolbarColor(getString(R.string.title_tabs),
            ContextCompat.getColor(mActivity, R.color.black),
            ContextCompat.getColor(mActivity, R.color.white),
            true);

    mActivity.lockDrawer();
    showToolbar(true);
}
```

All works fine in normal scenarios..MapFragment shows 'Navigation icon' and it's title and TabFragment shows 'Up arrow' and it's title.
 But **THE PROBLEM IS** that when I add two fragments in row then the TabFragment still shows the 'Navigation icon' clicking on which the TabFragment destroys and left menu opens. In a row I mean I added Map and Tab fragment immediately.

```
mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, mapFragment, "map").addToBackStack("map").commit();  
mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, tabsFragment, "tabs").addToBackStack("tabs").commit();
```

I did this because I want to launch tabs fragment to force user to fill in something that's missing.

WHAT I TRIED IS - I thought may be setting toolbar and it's titles have timing issue so I added tabsFragment after 3 seconds then it worked fine, shown up arrow on TabsFragment. So, it looks like methods to Actionbar or DrawerLayout and ActionbarDrawerToggle are not reentrant methods and has to be synchronized. I am not sure.

Any clue ?